# setVisibility is not working in DrawerNavigation

Tags: android

I am using a `NavigationView` in drawer and there is a item in the `Menu` which has `app:actionLayout` property directing to a `LinearLayout` containing a `TextView`, and the `TextView` has property `android:visibility="invisible"`. I want this `textview` to be visible when click on that `item` in `Menu`. but it is not working, i have added a `Toast` to check if click listener is working or not and find click listener is working but that `textView` is not being visible.

[image]

**Here is click Listener (Activity layout name is: `main_activity.xml`):**

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_kitchen_key:
                        View kitchenKeyLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_kitchen_key, null);
                        TextView kitchenKeyTextView = (TextView)kitchenKeyLayout.findViewById(R.id.show_kitchen_key);
                        kitchenKeyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

**Here is the `Menu item` :**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_kitchen_key"
    android:title="Kitchen Key"
    android:icon="@drawable/if_key"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_kitchen_key" />
```

**The property of menu item `app:actionLayout` directing to `nav_kitchen_key.xml` and here is `nav_kitchen_key.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/show_kitchen_key"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="2592"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/kitchen_key_background"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create new View, you should get from MenuItem, `MenuItem.getActionView()`

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_kitchen_key:
                        LinearLayout kitchenKeyLayout = (LinearLayout) item.getActionView();

                        TextView kitchenKeyTextView = (TextView)kitchenKeyLayout.findViewById(R.id.show_kitchen_key);
                        kitchenKeyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `View kitchenKeyLayout = item.getActionView();` is working fine. should it need to cast in LinearLayout like you provided in your answer, is there any difference between them.

Comment: item.getActionView() will return View only, As long as you are not going to use the property of LinearLayout you can use View. I just add that to make sure that the root view of your XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

You get a view from getActionView

```
LinearLayout kitchenKeyLayout = (LinearLayout) item.getActionView();
    // This returns the container layout  

TextView kitchenKeyTextView = (TextView)kitchenKeyLayout.findViewById(R.id.show_kitchen_key);
                            kitchenKeyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

kitchenKeyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: the item is not in header, it is in menu

Comment: updated post with new image. kitchen key need to be click

Comment: check it And You have to find your parent view